# Родовий відмінок назв річок: чому Дніпро - Дніпра, але Дон - Дону?

Tags: власні-назви, правопис, відмінювання, орфографія, родовий-відмінок

Назва річки "Дніпро" в родовому відмінку буде звучати як *"Дніпра"*.
Назва річки "Дон" в родовому відмінку буде звучати як *"Дону"*.

Правило про про особливості відмінювання іменників в родовому відмінку зазначає:

> В родовому відмінку закінчення `-а`; `-я` мають слова, що позначають чітко окреслені предмети, міста, річки та терміни.

Друга частина цього ж правила повідомляє:

> В родовому відмінку закінчення `-у`; `-ю` мають слова, що позначають речі, які не мають чітких контурів, а також речовини та матеріали, установи, географічні назви, країни, краї та річки.

Як спираючись на ці правила можна пояснити правопис слів **"Дніпро"** і **"Дон"** в родовому відмінку, адже обидва ці слова належать категорії річки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обидва іменники належать до другої відміни. В [українському правописі](http://www.pravopys.net/#search=48-60) зазначено:

> Іменники чол. роду в родовому відмінку однини приймають закінчення -а (у твердій та мішаній групах), -я (у м’якій групі), коли вони означають:
>
> ...інші географічні назви з наголосом у родовому відмінку на кінцевому складі, а також із суфіксами присвійності -ов, -ев (-єв), -ин (-їн): Дінця́, Дністра́, Іртиша́, Колгу́єва, Орла́, Остра́, Пиря́тина, Псла, Пско́ва, Те́терева.
>
> Закінчення -у (у твердій і мішаній групах), -ю (у м’якій групі) мають іменники чоловічого роду на приголосний, коли вони означають:
>
> Назви річок (крім зазначених у п. 1), озер, гір, островів, півостровів, країн, областей і т. ін.: Аму́ру, Бу́гу, Га́нгу, До́ну, Дуна́ю, Єнісе́ю, Ні́лу, Ре́йну, Се́йму; Байка́лу, Ельто́ну, Мічига́ну, Сві́тязю, Ча́ду; Алта́ю, Ельбру́су, Памі́ру, Ура́лу; Ко́тліну, Кі́пру, Кри́ту, Ро́досу, Сахалі́ну, Ка́ніну, Пелопонне́су; Алжи́ру, Афганіста́ну, Казахста́ну, Єги́пту, Іра́ку, Кита́ю; Донба́су, Ельза́су, Кавка́зу, Сибі́ру.

Отже, слово *Дніпро* підпадає під перше правило, оскільки в родовому відмінку має наголос на кінцевому складі - Дніпра́, а *Дон* - під друге правило - До́ну.
Для підтвердження ще одне [джерело](http://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_and_spelling/nouns_ends_II_case_masculine%20_singular.html).